# How to get values from two textboxes and display on third on button click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I two groups and every group have two textboxes. Now I want get values of all text boxes and display in third in this format:
2 apple, 3 watermelon

I will explain better with example:

```
I want this:

Group 1
Textbox1 = 2
Textbox2 = apple

Group 2
Textbox1 = 3
Textbox2 = watermelon

and third should looks like this:
Textbox3 = 2 apple, 3 watermelon
```

This is simple html code:

```
<input type="text" name="text1"><br />
<input type="text" name="text2"><br />

<br/><br/>

<input type="text" name="text1"><br />
<input type="text" name="text2"><br />

<input type="submit" value="Add" id="getValue">

<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="text3" />
```

I have tried to do like this, and works only with textbox 1, I don't know how to add second textbox in javascript.

```
$(function () {

            $('#getValue').click(function() {
                $('#text3').val('');
                var values = [];

                $('input[name="text1"]').each(function(i, elem) {
                    $("#text3").val(($("#text3").val() + ', ' + $(elem).val()).replace(/^, /, ''));
                });


            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#getValue').click(function() {
    let finalStr = "";
    let val;
    $('input.inputText').each(function(i, elem) {
      val = $(elem).val().replace(",", "");
      if (val) {
        val = (!(i % 2) && (i > 0)) ? ", " + val: " " + val;
        finalStr += val;
      }
      $("#text3").val(finalStr.trim());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text1" class="inputText"><br />
<input type="text" name="text2" class="inputText"><br />

<br/><br/>

<input type="text" name="text1" class="inputText"><br />
<input type="text" name="text2" class="inputText"><br />

<input type="submit" value="Add" id="getValue">

<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="text3" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. This works with dynamic table too.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done in a simpler way if you name each input differently. Like this:

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="group1-text1"><br />
<input type="text" name="group1-text2"><br />

<br/><br/>

<input type="text" name="group2-text1"><br />
<input type="text" name="group2-text2"><br />

<input type="submit" value="Add" id="getValue">

<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="text3" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#getValue').click(function() {
        let group1 = $('input[name="group1-text1"]').val() + ' ' + $('input[name="group1-text2"]').val();
        let group2 = $('input[name="group2-text1"]').val() + ' ' + $('input[name="group2-text2"]').val();
        let text3 = group1 + ', ' + group2;
        $('#text3').val(text3);
    });
});
```